# Can you trust jDownloader2?

Tags: download, jdownloader

As you can see the question above, my question is "Can you trust jDownloader2?"

As far as I know, jDownloader2 helps users to download files from One-Click-Hoster. JDownloader2 will automatically set all downloadable parts in a queue and will download each of them, when jDownloader2 has finished the download part before.

But what I am really worried about jDownloader2 is, does jDownloader2 really **only** download the file(s), **without** uploading them at the same time and / or after it finished the downloads.

So what I want to know is just, if jDownloader **only** downloads them. I know in the name is written "downloader", but I mean a name is just a name. So I thought I ask some people that made experience with it, before I am going to use it.

Do you have also made some experienece that you can share, just to let me know, what I have to consider when I am using jDownloader2?

I would be grateful for any answer and any advice or experience.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It isn't clear what your concern is.  What are you thinking might get uploaded?  i.e., concern that it's malware and might upload personal data from your machine?  It might act like a torrent and turn your machine into a source without your permission?  Did you do any research or come across an article that triggered this concern?  If it wasn't for your history on SO, people might mistake this for spam bait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDownloader is a download manager, and will thus only download stuff, no worries. Remember, you might still do something illegal if you are downloading copyrighted material! In most countries, only downloading will not be pursued though.

I highly suggest that you inform yourself further about the legal situation, so that you can make an informed decision on wether or not you want to download something. Also, keep in mind to check the downloaded stuff for viruses, using an up-to-date virus scanner!

Answer (score 1):

JDownloader only downloads the files. It's not a p2p sharing program. 
If you have doubts you can check the code: http://beta.jdownloader.org/developmentquicktutorial